# changing fixed-top to make an affix

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The bootstrap affix is not working with conflicting styles and at this point I like my design too much to let go of it for the example version [like this.](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp)

I later realized that affix could be easily done by just changing fixed-top in bootstrap. Currently, my css and onload js looks like this:

css:

```
.fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 70px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
    }
.badli .fixed-top{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px!important;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
    transition: 0.5s;
    }
```

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(document).scrollTop() > 70) {
            $('.navbar').addClass('badli');
            }
            else {
            $('.navbar').removeClass('badli'); }
            });
</script>
```

html:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
```

### So my question is:

Why wont the **top** attribute in *.fixed-top* change from 70px to 0px when `<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">` changes to `<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded badli">`

I'm targeting .badli right? So when `.badli` appears, shouldn't `.badli .fixed-top` also execute? Where have I gone wrong. Where do I start to get a good idea of this? Answers and references would be tremendous help

Comment: change `.badli .fixed-top` to `.badli.fixed-top`?

Comment: how could I have overlooked that! wow thanks!

Comment: if there is a `<div id="prenav"></div>` how can I do something like `.badli #prenav{/*css here*/}` so that when .badli is added in one class, some other classes/ids are also affected. I realise that I'm trying to use .badli as a flag here. Since js is being used already, is it more appropriate to use a js flag? Is what I'm asking, not possible in CSS? @MichaelCoker